# SQL Update WHERE IN subquery has stopped working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table. (there are other fields but Id and Lang are all that matter here.)

```sql
CREATE TABLE Request 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Lang nvarchar(20) NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a user-defined table type.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntList AS TABLE 
(
    Item int NOT NULL
)
```

Finally, I have a stored procedure that takes in a variable for my table type to update the Lang field for all the specified Ids.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE BulkUpdLang
    @ids as IntList READONLY,
    @lang as nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Request
    SET Lang = @lang
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT Item FROM @ids);
END
```

This was working fine and for some reason, has stopped. It now blows up with the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Assuming MyTable has 10 items with Ids 1-10, here is what I have tried:

```sql
declare @ids IntList;
insert into @ids
    select 3 union all
    select 4 union all
    select 5;

-- This is how I test the sproc
-- EXEC BulkUpdLang @ids, 'en-us';

-- This is just a select and works just fine.
--Select * from Request
--    Where Id in (Select Item From @ids);

-- This WAS working, but now throws the subquery error.
Update Request
Set Lang = 'en-us'
Where Id in (Select Item From @ids);

-- This works as expected. Unfortunately, the Ids need to be a variable.
--Update Request
--Set Lang = 'en-us'
--Where Id in (3, 4, 5);

-- This also throws the subquery error.
--Merge Request as Req
--Using @ids as Ids -- "Using (Select Item From @ids) as Ids" changes nothing
--on Req.Id = Ids.Item
--when matched then
--update set
--    Req.Lang = 'en-us';

-- This also throws the subquery error.
--Update Request
--Set Lang = 'en-us'
--From (Select Item From @ids) Ids
--Where Id = Ids.Item;
```

The thing that drives me crazy is that this WAS working. I'm inclined to believe that some SQL server setting has changed how it treats the subquery. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm losing my mind!

---

There is also a trigger on this table:

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Request_Status_Audit]
    ON [dbo].[Request]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @oldStatus nvarchar(15) = (SELECT [Status] FROM Deleted);
    DECLARE @newStatus nvarchar(15) = (SELECT [Status] FROM Inserted);
    
    IF (@oldStatus <> @newStatus) BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_RequestStatus (RequestId, StatusDate, StatusValue)
            SELECT Inserted.Id, GETDATE(), Inserted.[Status]
            FROM Inserted;
    END

    -- data retention
    DELETE FROM dbo.Audit_RequestStatus
    WHERE StatusDate < DATEADD(YEAR, -6, GETDATE());

END
```

Comment: This code will not generate that error. I bet someone created a bad trigger on the table.

Comment: THERE IS A TRIGGER! I rarely use them and didn't even consider that. Nice catch! Is there a way to disable this trigger for this one transaction within the sproc?

Comment: Don't disable the trigger, fix it.

Comment: Although you could disable the trigger in the proc, don't go there. I agree when @Larnu, you should fix it (or drop it).

Comment: This trigger is simply an audit log to another table. I don't even know what to fix for it. I'll add it to the end of the question for reference.

Comment: I got it working with a transaction and disable/enable trigger in the sproc. But as you said, I would prefer to fix the trigger. If someone suggests a fix for that, I will use that and accept it as the answer.

Comment: Your trigger is not set-based. What will be the value for those variables for any update of more than 1 rows?

Comment: That's a clasical bug with SQL Server triggers that don't consider multirow instructions. Instead of extracting ids into individual variables, treat everything with set-based constructs.

Answer (score 1):

**Your trigger does not deal with multi-row inserts and updates (nor with 0-row either)**, as is well documented [by Brent Ozar (The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers)](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) and others.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Request_Status_Audit]
    ON [dbo].[Request]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT UPDATE([Status]) OR NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT Id, [Status]
            FROM inserted
            EXCEPT
            SELECT Id, [Status]
            FROM deleted
        )
        RETURN ;
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_RequestStatus (RequestId, StatusDate, StatusValue)
        SELECT i.Id, GETDATE(), i.[Status]
        FROM (
            SELECT Id, [Status]
            FROM inserted
            EXCEPT
            SELECT Id, [Status]
            FROM deleted
        ) i;

    -- data retention
    DELETE FROM dbo.Audit_RequestStatus
    WHERE StatusDate < DATEADD(YEAR, -6, GETDATE());

GO
```

**Notes:**

- Compare necessary columns in `inserted` and `deleted` to see if there are changes, check also the `UPDATE` function (note that `UPDATE` only tells you if the column was present in the query, not if data actually changed), and bail out early if you can.
- In your `INSERT` again do the check for changed columns
- I would strongly advise to move the `DELETE` out into an Agent job.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a trigger with a subquery and I incorrectly assumed there would always be one result. Apparently, I fell into a classic gotcha. Based on comments and links people provided, I updated the trigger to this and now all works as expected.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_RequestStatus (RequestId, StatusDate, StatusValue)
    SELECT Inserted.Id, GETDATE(), Inserted.[Status]
    FROM Inserted
    JOIN Deleted ON Inserted.Id = Deleted.Id
    WHERE Inserted.[Status] <> Deleted.[Status];
```

Credit goes to Dan Guzman and Alejandro for helping me develop this fix.

Comment: This never does anything on an INSERT (as there is no record in the INSERTED table). If that's correct, the trigger should be defined for UPDATE only, but currently it fires on INSERT too.  Also, if the status is NULLable, this code doesn't cope with that (though neither did the original).

Comment: Try using set-based operators such as `EXCEPT` as I have done, it will avoid the issues mentioned by @MatBailie